# How to push one object inside another object in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In project there are two objects as below

**Object 1**

```
var mainObject = { 
                    'JobDetailID' :  2083,
                    'StartDateTime' : "2016/12/20 12:43:41 PM",
                    'EndDateTime' : "2016/12/20 12:43:41 PM",
                    'Enablechk' : 0,
                    'EAlert' : 0,
                 }
```

**Object 2**

```
var data = {
                    'TriggerType' : 1,
                    'MinuteEvery' : 13
                }
```

What i want is merging this two objects, so that the result look like as below

```
var totalData = {
                'JobDetailID' :  2083,
                'StartDateTime' : "2016/12/20 12:43:41 PM",
                'EndDateTime' : "2016/12/20 12:43:41 PM",
                'Enablechk' : 0,
                'EAlert' : 0,
                'TriggerType' : 1,
                'MinuteEvery' : 13
}
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var totalData = Object.assign(mainObject, data);
```

Note that this is a "destructive" (overwriting) update of `mainObject`. If you don't want `mainObject` to be modified, then do:

```
var totalData = Object.assign({}, mainObject, data);
```